# Delete last section in Word VBA without the previous heading getting overwritten

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code that I found when googleing on the problem. The problem with this code is that it overwrites the next-to-last section header (and footer though I only need the header preserved) to that of the last section, which is the default (strange) behavior of Word.

Is there a workaround to this in VBA?

Here is the code that has the inherent fault:

```
Sub DeleteLastSection()
'Deletes last section of a document including
'the section break
Dim doc As Document
Dim rng As Range
Dim ctr As Integer
Set doc = ActiveDocument
ctr = doc.Sections.Count
Set rng = doc.Sections(ctr).Range
Dim myheader As HeaderFooter
If ctr > 1 Then
    With rng
        .Select
        .MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        .Delete
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

**Note:** The entire range of the last section is being deleted by the code and that is the required behavior. The inherent problem in the default behavior of Word is what I needed a workaround for in VBA code. One can found complex manual procedures to avoid it, but I needed a simple approach in code.

Comment: Background to the issue, supporting the contribution by @Sam (which can be included in the answer, if you wish): Word always, by default, has one section. This section is associated with the last paragraph mark and *cannot* be removed. New sections are always created *before* the original section. Section formatting is always "held" in the section break *following* a section. So removing the last *visible* section break will always retain the section formatting of that last section, for which there is no visible section break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking more into this on my own (I had to solve the issue in short order and could not wait), I came to the same conclusion as was noted in the comment by @CindyMeister that when deleting the last "section break" in actual fact the next-to-last section is being deleted, and what data and formatting heretofore belonged to the last section is *apparently* inherited by the *new* last section (i.e. the earlier next-to-last section). But in reality the last section remained and only the section break was deleted, so what was deleted was the next-to-last section (and the actual pages from the last section).

I found that the `LinkToPrevious` property of the `HeaderFooter` object allows a simplistic approach to "inherit" the settings from the previous section.

So by adding a few lines to set this property to `true` in each instance and then change it back to `false`, I can get the required behavior of the next-to-last section remaining the same as before.

(Please note that it worked for me because I simply had different text in the primary header, and did not have special formatting and else. But I suspect that based on the workings of the `LinkToPrevious` property this is a panacea. Please comment if otherwise.)

These are the lines to set the property:

```
for each hf in .Sections(1).Headers
    hf.LinkToPrevious = True
    hf.LinkToPrevious = False
next

for each hf in .Sections(1).Footers
    hf.LinkToPrevious = True
    hf.LinkToPrevious = False
next
```

The full working code for progeny:

```
Sub DeleteLastSection()
'Deletes last section of a document including
'the section break
Dim doc As Document
Dim rng As Range
Dim ctr As Integer
Set doc = ActiveDocument
ctr = doc.Sections.Count
Set rng = doc.Sections(ctr).Range
Dim myheader As HeaderFooter
If ctr > 1 Then
    With rng
        'Added lines to "inherit" the settings from the next-to-last section
        for each hf in .Sections(1).Headers
            hf.LinkToPrevious = True
            hf.LinkToPrevious = False
        next
        for each hf in .Sections(1).Footers
            hf.LinkToPrevious = True
            hf.LinkToPrevious = False
        next

        .Select
        .MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        .Delete
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here lies in the fact that the section break carries the section information. If you delete it, the last section becomes part of the section before. The trick I use below is to create a continuous section break instead of a page break, and then do all the rest:

```
Sub DeleteLastSection()
    'Deletes last section of a document including
    'the section break
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim NewEndOfDocument As Range
    Dim ctr As Integer
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    ctr = doc.Sections.Count
    Set rng = doc.Sections(ctr).Range                   

    If ctr > 1 Then
        ' Create a section break at the end of the second to last section
        Set NewEndOfDocument = doc.Sections(ctr - 1).Range
        NewEndOfDocument.EndOf wdSection, wdMove
        doc.Sections.Add NewEndOfDocument, wdSectionContinuous

        With rng
            .Select
            .MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
            .Delete
        End With
    End If                
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a smart workaround. Deserved upvote. Though I want to note that with this we actually do not delete the last section, only the pages thereof. I was looking for a solution that would get rid for the extra section break to have a clean document. I posted a workaround now as an answer that I found to resolve the issue using the `LinkToPrevious` property.

Comment: I have a ton of documents where the final section break is a New Page type which was adds unnecessary blank pages at the end. Nothing I tried would convert them to a Continuous type, but this snippet does the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily, deleting a Section break causes the Section preceding the break to assume the page layout of the following Section. The following macro works the other way, across multiple (selected) Section breaks. All common page layout issues (margins, page orientation, text columns, headers & footers) are addressed. As you can see by studying the code, it's no trivial task to do all these things.

```
Sub MergeSections()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sPageHght As Single, sPageWdth As Single
Dim sHeaderDist As Single, sFooterDist As Single
Dim sTMargin As Single, sBMargin As Single
Dim sLMargin As Single, sRMargin As Single
Dim sGutter As Single, sGutterPos As Single
Dim lPaperSize As Long, lGutterStyle As Long
Dim lMirrorMargins As Long, lVerticalAlignment As Long
Dim lScnStart As Long, lScnDir As Long
Dim lOddEvenHdFt As Long, lDiffFirstHdFt As Long
Dim bTwoPagesOnOne As Boolean, bBkFldPrnt As Boolean
Dim bBkFldPrnShts As Boolean, bBkFldRevPrnt As Boolean
Dim lOrientation As Long, oHdFt As HeaderFooter
Dim Sctn1 As Section, Sctn2 As Section
With Selection
  If .Sections.Count = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Selection does not span a Section break", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Set Sctn1 = .Sections.First: Set Sctn2 = .Sections.Last
  With Sctn1.PageSetup
    lPaperSize = .PaperSize
    lGutterStyle = .GutterStyle
    lOrientation = .Orientation
    lMirrorMargins = .MirrorMargins
    lScnStart = .SectionStart
    lScnDir = .SectionDirection
    lOddEvenHdFt = .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter
    lDiffFirstHdFt = .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter
    lVerticalAlignment = .VerticalAlignment
    sPageHght = .PageHeight
    sPageWdth = .PageWidth
    sTMargin = .TopMargin
    sBMargin = .BottomMargin
    sLMargin = .LeftMargin
    sRMargin = .RightMargin
    sGutter = .Gutter
    sGutterPos = .GutterPos
    sHeaderDist = .HeaderDistance
    sFooterDist = .FooterDistance
    bTwoPagesOnOne = .TwoPagesOnOne
    bBkFldPrnt = .BookFoldPrinting
    bBkFldPrnShts = .BookFoldPrintingSheets
    bBkFldRevPrnt = .BookFoldRevPrinting
  End With
  With Sctn2.PageSetup
    .GutterStyle = lGutterStyle
    .MirrorMargins = lMirrorMargins
    .SectionStart = lScnStart
    .SectionDirection = lScnDir
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = lOddEvenHdFt
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = lDiffFirstHdFt
    .VerticalAlignment = lVerticalAlignment
    .PageHeight = sPageHght
    .PageWidth = sPageWdth
    .TopMargin = sTMargin
    .BottomMargin = sBMargin
    .LeftMargin = sLMargin
    .RightMargin = sRMargin
    .Gutter = sGutter
    .GutterPos = sGutterPos
    .HeaderDistance = sHeaderDist
    .FooterDistance = sFooterDist
    .TwoPagesOnOne = bTwoPagesOnOne
    .BookFoldPrinting = bBkFldPrnt
    .BookFoldPrintingSheets = bBkFldPrnShts
    .BookFoldRevPrinting = bBkFldRevPrnt
    .PaperSize = lPaperSize
    .Orientation = lOrientation
  End With
  With Sctn2
    For Each oHdFt In .Footers
      oHdFt.LinkToPrevious = Sctn1.Footers(oHdFt.Index).LinkToPrevious
      If oHdFt.LinkToPrevious = False Then
        Sctn1.Headers(oHdFt.Index).Range.Copy
        oHdFt.Range.Paste
      End If
    Next
    For Each oHdFt In .Headers
      oHdFt.LinkToPrevious = Sctn1.Headers(oHdFt.Index).LinkToPrevious
      If oHdFt.LinkToPrevious = False Then
        Sctn1.Headers(oHdFt.Index).Range.Copy
        oHdFt.Range.Paste
      End If
    Next
  End With
  While .Sections.Count > 1
    .Sections.First.Range.Characters.Last.Delete
  Wend
  Set Sctn1 = Nothing: Set Sctn2 = Nothing
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the last section of a word document is not a trivial task.

Things you might have to do if items are different between the 'next to last' and 'last' section of a document.

1. Ensure that in the last section  any 'linktoprevious' in a header or footer is set to to false
2. Copy all headers and footers from the next to last section to the last section
3. Copy the relevant page format items of the next to last section to the last section (paper size, orientation, margins etc)
4. Get the range for the last section in the document.  Move the end of the range backward until the ascii value is >=32.

Then you can safely delete the adjusted range from your document without any nasty side effects

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I just created that works well:

```
Sub DeleteLastPage() 
    Dim pgSetUp As PageSetup
    Dim iSect As Integer
            iSect = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count - 1
    Set pgSetUp = ActiveDocument.Sections(iSect).PageSetup
    With ActiveDocument.Sections.Last.PageSetup
        .LineNumbering.Active = pgSetUp.LineNumbering.Active
        .Orientation = pgSetUp.Orientation
        .TopMargin = pgSetUp.TopMargin
        .BottomMargin = pgSetUp.BottomMargin
        .LeftMargin = pgSetUp.LeftMargin
        .RightMargin = pgSetUp.RightMargin
        .Gutter = pgSetUp.Gutter
        .HeaderDistance = pgSetUp.HeaderDistance
        .FooterDistance = pgSetUp.FooterDistance
        .PageWidth = pgSetUp.PageWidth
        .PageHeight = pgSetUp.PageHeight
        .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = pgSetUp.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = pgSetUp.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter
        .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
    End With
    With ActiveDocument.Sections.Last.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        .LinkToPrevious = true
    End With
    With ActiveDocument.Sections.Last.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        .LinkToPrevious = true
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Sections.Last.Range.Characters.Delete
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter,Count:=1
End Sub
```